# Portfolio optimization with monte carlo sampling from predictive distribution

Tags: risk, monte-carlo, optimization, modern-portfolio-theory, portfolio-selection

Let's say we have a predictive distribution of expected returns for N assets. The distribution is not normal. We can interpret the dispersion in the distribution as reflection of our uncertainty (or estimation risk) in the expected returns.

Question - What is the set of optimal portfolio weights that is mean-variance efficient with some constraint for the predictive distribution? Of course, we do not know what possible realization from the predictive distribution Nature will select.

I will suggest some angles of attack and show their various flaws. This is a very real and challenging problem -- I'm hoping the community can crack this!

Approach 1 (Monte Carlo) : Sample from the multivariate predictive distribution. Find the weights corresponding to the mean-variance efficient portfolio for each sample. Repeat the procedure for 1,000 draws from the predictive distribution. Average the weights via some procedure (for example, average of the rank-associated mean variance portfolios per Michaud 1998).

The re-sampling approach has several major flaws as discussed by [Scherer](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=796625): if short-sales are allowed this will add noise to estimation; procedure will include mean-variance dominated assets in the presence of a long-only constraint; the shape of the efficient frontier excludes the feasible maximum return option which is not theoretically plausible; re-sampled allocations can produce portfolios that violate investment constraints;  and so on.

Approach 2 (Black-Litterman) : This knee-jerk answer doesn't work since the posterior is already provided here.

Approach 3 (Mean of Posterior): Sample from the predictive distribution N times. Collapse the distribution of expected returns into a single vector corresponding to each security's mean return.

The flaw here is that estimation risk is assumed away. This is a robust optimization problem where the goal is to identify weights that are approximately optimal under various realizations of market returns.

What might work?

Approach 4 (Complex objective function). Perhaps we could extend the objective function by summing over the mean-variance objective for each draw from the predictive distribution.

The mean-variance objective function for a single draw is: weights*expected return vector + wEw, where the expected return vector is a sampling from the predictive distribution, and E is the sample covariance matrix, and w is the vector we are solving for.

For multiple draws, the objective function = (w*expected return draw 1 + wEw) + (w*expected return draw 2 + wEw) + ... (w*expected return draw n + wEw)

This would be a lengthy objective function that is computationally intensive assuming 500 assets and 1,000 draws. Maybe some fast genetic algorithms could work in parallel. I also have not seen the literature discuss this approach although intuitively it seems sound.

Please poke holes and let me know if there is another approach.

Comment: Even though the predictive distribution is not normal, can it be modeled analytically or is it purely empirical?

Comment: It is purely empirical and cannot be modeled analytically.

Comment: I am not sure how exactly to solve your problem, but have you read Axioma's research paper on [Real World Case Studies in Portfolio Construction Using Robust Optimization](http://www.axiomainc.com/downloads/robust_optimization.pdf)?

Comment: This is an excellent paper, thank you. Another paper that solves for weights given some expected return vector and uncertainty dispersion is Robust Bayesian Allocation by Meucci: http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=681553

Comment: You should post whatever approach you ultimately go with as your answer.  At least 7 people besides me also thought your question is very interesting.

Comment: Will do - I should have an approach by end of month

Comment: before even the start, how are you deciding how to form a predictive distribution? is it a function of in-sample optimized weights and the individual asset return distributions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tools from the field of [stochastic optimizatio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_optimization)n are best suited for these problems. In particular, attached is a [paper](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/papers/HannahPowellBlei2010a.pdf) on non-parametric density estimation for stochastic optimization that describes an algorithm if state variables can be associated with draws from the predictive distribution.

Here's another approach by [Kuhn](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~pp500/pubs/KuhnParpasRustem.pdf). These are all one-period solutions. Multi-period solutions would require dynamic programming and its solutions cannot be resolved within the expected lifespan of the universe. At least that bounds the problem space!

Comment: Did you mean *stochastic programming*?

Comment: could the broken links be updated, and does this answer still stand with advances made since?

Comment: @develarist Did you find the papers online? The link doesn't work

Comment: I believe the Kuhn paper was *Kuhn; Parpas; Rustem Bound-based decision rules in multistage stochastic programming, Kybernetica, Jan 2008* https://docplayer.net/213708500-Kybernetika-daniel-kuhn-panos-parpas-berc-rustem-bound-based-decision-rules-in-multistage-stochastic-programming.html or https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/135840/Kybernetika_44-2008-2_2.pdf