# Sampling in Portfolio Optimization

Tags: portfolio-optimization, asset-allocation

I recently came across the following method for portfolio optimization: Let $Y$ be a random variable that describes the returns of $n$ assets. Fix a constraint matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$. Then, we sample from $Y$ and calculate the weights $x$ that maximize returns under the constraints $Ax \ge b$. Finally, we average over all optimal allocations to compute the final weights $\bar x$.

Since the set $\{ Ax \ge b\} $ is convex, we can be sure that $\bar x$ also satisfies the constraints. Thus, I think the practical idea is that $\bar x$ will be a good feasible compromise between extreme cases of $Y$ while still somewhat maximizing the objective function.

But from a statistical point of view, it is unclear to be why this would be a good procedure. Why don't we use the mean of $Y$ directly? Is this some kind of Bayesian approach?

**Update**

I think my statistical concerns were essentially adressed [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1577/portfolio-optimization-with-monte-carlo-sampling-from-predictive-distribution) and the method was discussed in the paper mentioned there (though with a different objective function including a quadratic term that reflects risk)

Comment: It's an interesting question. The only thing I can think of is that you have the density and it's easy to sample from  but not easy to calculate the mean and the variance of. This is what monte carlo markov chains ( so, yes bayesian ) are often used for, namely to sample from the distribution when you don't have closed form expressions for the mean and the variance. The question doesn't explicitly state the density but that seems to me like the only reason that one wouldn't use the mean and the variances directly.

Comment: @markleeds Indeed the density of $Y$ is not known in this case. But I guess we could approximate the mean $y$ directly by sampling, and then optimize w.r.t this specific $y$. So it is unclear to me why we optimize for samples and only then average over all weights. Would you expect this approach to be more "robust"?

Comment: Interesting. Where did you see ths algorithm?

Comment: It's basically the condensed mathematical version of what I heard from a friend

Comment: Such linear constraints will not reflect risk. So this will miss one of the two interesting aspects of portfolio optimization.

Comment: What about tail risk inequalities? They can be linear...

Comment: Hi Claudio: I'm not commenting her about the lack of constraints on variance but that's a valid point by g g. As far as what you asked me, what I'm not clear on is how you sample from $Y$ if you don't have the density ?  Do, you mean that have a sample of observations that are reflective of the $Y$ population and you sample from that ? I might be confused about this part because not knowing the density yet being able generate observations from $Y$ is not clear to me.

Comment: Hi Mark, from what I understood the joint density is complicated but we can sample from it (perhaps by using the conditionals as in MCMC). I am sorry that I can't be more specific, I am trying to make sense of all of this myself and thought maybe someone recognizes this approach as "xyz". I am now trying to understand what is discussed in this post https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1577/portfolio-optimization-with-monte-carlo-sampling-from-predictive-distribution

Comment: Hi: yes, in that case, the MCMC approach sounds reasonable if you don't have a straightforward density. For the concept behind MCMC,  chib and greenberg have a good introductory  article but, for implementations you probably need a decent text that really goes into the gory details of MCMC.  It's been so long that I can't tell you what texts I've used and all of my texts are in storage. Plus, since it's been about 10 years, there may be new material that's come out since that I am not familiar with. Still the chib and greenberg paper is a good place to start.

Comment: Hi Claudio: This is the paper that I was referring to. I don't remember if it's enough for learning how to go about dealing with a specific problem but I remember it being quite helpful for someone without previous exposure.  I hope it helps some.  https://www2.stat.duke.edu/~scs/Courses/Stat376/Papers/Basic/ChibGreenberg1995.pdf

Comment: The approach is also called Michaud portfolio resampling. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampled_efficient_frontier

Comment: The argument against resampling is typically 1) it generates less expected utility than a classical mean-variance optimal portfolio, 2) the smooth behavior of the resampled frontier is only produced when inequality constraints are used (most common being the long only)

Comment: Claudio: I would read the paper referenced in the wikipedia article that John provided because the wiki just says "re-sampled" and there are many ways to re-sample so I would check that they are using MCMC for the re-sampling. They may be using some other approach that I'm not aware of and I don't want to lead you down the wrong path. MCMC can be a monster to grapple with.

Comment: the way you set the problem seems strange to me @ClaudioMoneo; I agree with @g g that you should have something reflecting risk aversion in it. Do you really want to solve $\max_x x^T Y$ under the constraint that $A x\geq b$? it seems to me a rather trivial problem. Usually one solves $\max_x x^T Y - {\rm risk}(x)$ under the constraint that $A x\geq b$.

Comment: @lehalle I was thinking of something like a tail risk constraint (such as conditional value at risk, which gives rise to a linear constraint). Mathematically that was the easiest version of this method that I could think of (linear program with linear constraints and uncertainty regarding one parameter)